# ASMX WebService calling DLL (P.Invoke)

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx, unmanaged

I'm using an old fashioned ASMX WebService (not WCF) which internally calls an unmanaged DLL (via PInvoke). I don't get any exception but it does not work as expected. The same code in a regular WinForms application works fine.

I think it's because of the working directory when debugging the WebService in VisualStudio. The working directory is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0 and I guess the unmanaged DLL's are missing. But in the \bin folder of my project all DLL's are there.

Is there a way to tell configure the service accordingly or do I need special access rights?

PS: sorry for the newbie question.

Here's some part of the code:

**First**: The service accepts some vector graphics that are then projected by laser-projector.

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.myDomain.eu/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class BeamerService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public void ShowBounds()
    {
        // ToDo: construct some graphics

        // ToDo: get laser/DAC
        DAC dac;
        if (!Laser.DAC.TryInitializeAny(out dac))
        {
            // DAC not connected
            return;
        }

        // ToDo: send graphics to DAC
```

**Second**: Get access to the laser-device which is connected to the computer via USB.

```
    public static bool TryInitializeAny(out DAC dac)
    {
        return UniversalDAC.TryInitialize(ControllerTypes.Netlase, ControllerType.Netlase, out dac);
    }
```

**Third**: Use unmanaged DLL (not mine) to search for connected devices and acquire the first one. All lines that start with "DrLava" are P.Invoke calls to unmanaged code.

```
    public static bool TryInitialize(ControllerTypes types, ControllerType type, out DAC dac, DeviceChooser deviceChooser = null)
    {
        try
        {
            uint deviceCount = 0;
            if (DrLava.LDL_Init((uint)ConvertToNativeMask(types), ref deviceCount) != NativeConstants.DAC_OK)
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Could not intialize DAC with '{0}'", type));

            uint device = deviceChooser == null ? 0 : deviceChooser(deviceCount);

            uint tType = 0;
            uint tEnum = 0;
            var sName = new StringBuilder(128);
            if (DrLava.LDL_GetDACInfo(device, sName, (uint)sName.Length, ref tType, ref tEnum) != NativeConstants.DAC_OK)
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Could retriev name of DAC device number {0} with '{1}'.", device, type));

            if (DrLava.LDL_DAC_Init(device) != NativeConstants.DAC_OK)
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Could not intialize DAC with '{0}' using device number {1}", type, device));

            dac = new UniversalDAC(type, sName.ToString(), device);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.Error("Could not initialize DAC.Instance with '{0}'. {1}", type, ex);
        }

        dac = null;
        return false;
    }
```

So, the problem is in step 3. If I run the code in a console or WinForms application, the connected USB is found and I can use it. If I run the same code in a WebService, the first line in step 3 (DrLava.LDL_Init) will yield no results.

Comment: Please do explain what "I don't get any exception but it does not work as expected" mean. What is the function you call via P/Invoke? Expected result? Actual result?

Comment: what signature are you using for PInvoke.?

Comment: I'm calling some methods of an unmanaged DLL that then looks for connected USB devices from different vendors (using the DLL/driver of each vendor). So it's MyDLL(1)-->UnmanagedDLL(1)-->VendorDLLs(many)

Comment: share the code please.

Comment: @Jodha I edited my question and added sample source code. Hopefully you have an idea.

Comment: I recommend that you find out from the vendors whether their unmanaged code is meant to run in a server-type application. It may only be intended for use in Windows Forms or native Windows GUI applications. In particular, it may not be thread-safe.

Comment: I guess that's not the question of what the code is designed for. It's a problem of where some DLL's are located. This is because the unmanaged DLL uses several other DLL's (drivers) to search for the connected USB devides. Or it's a security issue. Still working on it.

Comment: What makes you think it has to do with where the DLLs are located?

Comment: System.IO.Directory.CurrentDirectory is the debugging dir of VisualStudio's dev-webserver. I think the first unmanaged DLL tries to locate the driver DLL's that it need to search for the USB devices. But instead of throwing an exception that the DLL's are not there, it simply returns null.